# How to inspect a Parameterized method?

Tags: java, generics, parameterized

I would like to convert a Number form a String with such a method :

```
class MathUtils{

    public static <T extends Number> T convert(String str){

       try{
        //convert str depending on the parameter T

       }catch(Exception e){
          e.printStackTrace();
       }
    }
}
```

Then I call my function with :

```
 Float f = MathUtils.<Float>convert("2");
```

Unfortunately, even looking deeply in the debugger, I have no clue how to get this Float parameter. I just can have an hold on Number, but never Float.

There is a way to get the actual parameter of o Collection using ParameterizedType.getActualType(), but what for parameterized method ?

Thank you !

Comment: The defined method takes a string (just one parameter) and returns an instance of type T. Why are you trying to pass in two parameters? Just call `Float f = MathUtils.reconvert<Float>("2");`

Comment: Hi, I just changed this as soon as I posted it. I made different tests with methods convert and reconvert. But what a quick reply ! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In java, due to [type erasure](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html), you cannot infer the generic type like that. You'll have to change your method signature to

```
public static <T extends Number> T convert(Class<T> clazz, String str){

   if (clazz == Float.class)
   {
       ...
   }
   ...
}
```

and call `Float f = MathUtils.<Float>convert(Float.class, "2");`

Comment: I fear this :). There is twice the Float declaration wich is too much information, and that's why I would prefer something more pretty.

Comment: @NicolasZozol I know what you are saying. But unfortunately in java, you'll have to do that (unlike c#). But the good news is you cannot do `Float f = MathUtils.convert<Integer>(Float.class, "2");` You'll get a compilation error.

Comment: So why the parameterizedType.getActualTypeArguments works with Collections such as List<Float> ?

Comment: @NicolasZozol here's the source for [`ArrayList<T>`](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/ArrayList.java.html) can you point out which part you are talking about?

Comment: I worked on this (working) code : http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/generics.html#parametertypes   I do get the parameter

Comment: @Bala R You mean `Float f = MathUtils.<Integer>convert(Float.class, "2");` which can be written `Float f = MathUtils.convert(Float.class, "2");`. Still an atrocious way to do it.

Comment: you need to parameterize the method with <Float>, or to cast.
   `Float f = MathUtils.<Float>convert(Float.class, "2");`
It's pretty close to what I was usually doing :
  `Float f = MathUtils.<Float>convert(2f, "2");`
Then checking the instance of 2f

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline you are correct. @NicolasZozol passing `Float.class` is better because if you pass `2f` then you need reflection and using reflection is an expensive operation. Also the example you linked to does not involve a generic definition of something and trying to infer type. it's just using a defined generic type. They are two different things.

Comment: "They are two different things". You are right, I see now the difference. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a different method - name, interface and implementation - for each type.